# mat4 type in attribute shader

Tags: opengl-es, webgl, shader

how to send to a shader attribute with the MAT4 type?

```
attribute mat4 attr;
...
```

JS:

```
var attr=gl.getAttribLocation(_program,"attr");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.25.pdf) section 2.10.4

> When an attribute variable is declared as a `mat4`, its
>   matrix columns are taken from the (*x, y, z, w*) components of generic attributes *i*
>   through *i* + 3.

so

JS:

```
var row0Location = gl.getAttribLocation(_program, "attr");
var row1Location = row0Location + 1;
var row2Location = row0Location + 2;
var row3Location = row0Location + 3;
```

As for getting the data the most common way would be to put all the matrices in one buffer so

```
var matrices = new Float32Array(numMatrices * 16);

... // fill out your matrices

gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, matrices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
```

then to set up the attributes

```
var floatsPerRow = 4
var bytesPerRow = floatsPerRow * 4;
var bytesPerMatrix = bytesPerRow * 4;
var row0Offset = bytesPerRow * 0;
var row1Offset = bytesPerRow * 1;
var row2Offset = bytesPerRow * 2;
var row3Offset = bytesPerRow * 3;
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(row0Location);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(row0Location, floatsPerRow, gl.FLOAT, 
                       false, bytesPerMatrix, row0Offset);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(row1Location);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(row1Location, floatsPerRow, gl.FLOAT, 
                       false, bytesPerMatrix, row1Offset);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(row2Location);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(row2Location, floatsPerRow, gl.FLOAT, 
                       false, bytesPerMatrix, row2Offset);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(row3Location);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(row3Location, floatsPerRow, gl.FLOAT, 
                       false, bytesPerMatrix, row3Offset);
```

Something to be aware of. If you're debugging and you comment out `attr` in your shader then `row0Location` will be -1 and calling all the `gl.vertexAttrib` functions with a -1 location is a no-op which is good. But, because you compute the other locations `row1Location`, `row2Location` and `row3Location` will be valid attribute locations as far as WebGL is concern but invalid as far as your program is concerned. Not a big deal just something to keep in mind.

Comment: That depends on your data. See answer